# How to trigger once by any concurrent request without blocking all (or some of the others)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, critical-section

I've known the use of `lock` to ensure that one section of code can only be run by one thread/request/execution flow at a time. But I'm not so sure how to ensure that the event will be triggered just once without blocking some threads/requests. Here is what I've tried to help minimize the number of blocked concurrent requests:

```
static bool _isTriggered;
static bool _isTriggering;
static object _o = new object();
void _someMethod(){
    if(_isTriggered || _isTriggering) return;
    lock(_o){
       if(_isTriggered) return;
       _isTriggering = true;
       //do some long running task by triggering an event for all registered
       //handlers to do their own jobs ...
       //...                 
       _isTriggered = true;
       _isTriggering = false;
    }
}
```

There are multiple threads or requests accessing that `_someMethod` concurrently. So you can see that there may be some requests passing the first check but be blocked by the `lock`. When the first running through that `lock`, all the others (passed the first check but blocked before) will run through that section each by each but will return immediately due to the second `if` check. (ensuring that the event is triggered just once).

That `lock` is good if all the requests should run through the locked section of code. But here I just need one of them to run through that section, all the others should ignore (and really should not be blocked at all).

Do you have any code solution to this issue to help minimize the number of blocked requests (to even no request being blocked)?

### Update

Will this be ensured to be run exactly once (passing the check):

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool> _dict = ...;
if(!_dict.AddOrUpdate(someKey, false, (key, vl) => true)){
   //...
}
```

If that `.AddOrUpdate` always return `false` (as the added value) the first time, that would fit my requirement because all the next calls should call the update callback and return `true` (which will by-pass the `if` check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you perhaps create a variable `int i = 0`, and then whenever a thread gets to the critical section, it tries to `int result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref i, 1, 0)`? Then if `result == 0`, it means your thread is initializing, and otherwise it isn't.

Some things to consider in this scenario are

1. Do other threads have to wait for the critical section to finish initializing, or can they continue even when the critical section is not yet done? That could mean that the object is not initialized and is in some inconsistent state. If they do have to wait, maybe you could use Lazy or LazyInitializer instead.
2. Is there another way to run this initialization? Perhaps it would be a better option to run this when the application is starting, instead of lazily in a multi-threaded scenario.

Edit: your code might look like the following if I apply the `CompareExchange` approach:

```cs
static int i = 0;
void _someMethod(){
    int result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref i, 1, 0);
    if(result != 0) return;
    //do some long running task by triggering an event for all registered
    //handlers to do their own jobs ...
    //...                 
    }
}
```

Just make sure that if you later decide to access `i` for any other reason, you always do it with an `Interlocked` operation, otherwise you could be unsealing a Pandora's box of issues.

Comment: For 1, you can have the threads compete to store a `Task` each obtains from a separate `TaskCompletionSource`. Same kind of logic as the `int`. Issue with `Lazy` is that other callers are blocked rather than getting some nice `Task` they can use later.

Comment: I'm not sure how to exactly apply your idea in my code? Could you edit your answer with more detail? For your questions to make it clearer, actually my code is not doing any kind of initialization, all the static variables are also used for one group of requests (determined by some key data carried with them). In my snippet of code above, I simplified it to one group. The other threads can by-pass the critical section even when the triggering has not been done yet (even if it's failed).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it would be nice if you could add your own answer with a different idea, thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer to contain a code example. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: thanks for your edit, looks like I can understand it now. But when getting back to my original problem (as I said about grouping requests/threads), I think that trying to use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is no longer suitable, looks like I can use `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate` instead, do you think so? The value type can be `bool`, and the key type can be any containing data collected from each request/thread.

Comment: so the idea here is to use some `atomic operation method` like `Interlock.CompareExchange`, or as I think `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate` (as atomic as well), right after that we have a valid (and safe) value to check before proceeding.

Comment: In that case I don't think I understand enough about your use case. I thought the issue was you wanted to run the critical section *at most once*, and all other threads would pass through. So you're saying you want to run this method at most once for each point of data? Or please elaborate further...

Comment: @yawnston yes each group of threads (based on some specific data) should run through the section at most once. I'm going to ask another question about `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate`, actually your answer does satisfy what my original question posed. If possible please take a look at my **Update** in my original question for that extra question. Anyway sooner or later I'll accept your answer, if you could not help me with that extra-question, I will ask it in another separate question. Thanks!

Comment: I was actually unsure about this so I read up on ConcurrentDictionary a bit and it does seem like it would fit your use case. The code marked with `// ...` should indeed run at most once, since only a single thread (not necessarily the first to call that function) will be the one adding a value.

Comment: @yawnston actually I would like it to run at least once as well (so exactly once), I really doubt that somehow the `.AddOrUpdate` will return value updated (not added), and that will make the code inside `if` never run. I've tried a simple demo at here https://dotnetfiddle.net/8v4xQp - looks like there is a chance that it's not run (tested by clicking Run multiple times). So it's a pity that I cannot rely on `.AddOrUpdate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199664/discussion-between-yawnston-and-hopeless).